# problema al intentar rellenar una matriz automaticamente

Tags: c

tengo esta función, he estado probando distintas cosas pero no logro hacer que la matriz se rellene aautomaticamente a partir de un solo numero, por ejemplo: si introduzco el numero 3 la matriz se debería llenar a partir del numero 3, de esta forma: [3][4][5][6]
                                             [4][5][6][7]
y asi hasta el tamaño de la matriz que se quiera, no importa si es 3x3 o 3x6 etc

```
void eveMatriz(int prmMatriz[100][100],int longitudFila,int longitudColumna)
    {
    int controlMatriz;
    for(int i=0;i<longitudColumna;i++){

    for(int j=0;j<longitudFila;j++){

    prmMatriz[0][0]=scanf("%d",&controlMatriz);

    i=controlMatriz;
    j=i+1;

    printf("%d",prmMatriz[i][j]);


    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En ningún momento empiezas a llenar la matriz, salvo en esta línea:

```
prmMatriz[0][0]=scanf("%d",&controlMatriz);
```

Que la verdad para mi no tiene sentido, la expresión de la derecha lee las entradas que realizas por teclado y lo guarda dentro de un argumento que se pasa por referencia, la función devolverá un entero, que es el número de argumentos que pudo leer exitosamente, en este caso, lee una entrada y lo guarda dentro de `controlMatriz`, éstas lecturas de entrada lo haces dentro del bucle, por lo que si funcionara te pediría un dato `longitudFila*longitudColumna` veces, y guardaría 1 (si las lecturas fueron exitosas) en la misma ubicación (`prmMatriz[0][0]`) la misma cantidad de veces.

Si he entendido bien lo que quieres hacer, la lectura debería realizarse una sola vez fuera del bucle, sin almacenar el valor de retorno.

```
void eveMatriz(int prmMatriz[100][100],int longitudFila,int longitudColumna)
    {
    int controlMatriz;
    scanf("%d",&controlMatriz);//pidiendo el valor fuera del bucle

    for(int i=0;i<longitudColumna;i++){

    for(int j=0;j<longitudFila;j++){

    prmMatriz[i][j]=controlMatriz+j;//aquí es donde se rellena la matriz

    }
    controlMatriz++;
    }
}
```

Para poner a prueba la función utilicé el siguiente `main`.

```
int main(){
  int matriz[100][100];
  int lx=4;//matriz de 4x4
  int ly=4;
  eveMatriz(matriz,lx,ly);

  //imprimiendo la matriz.
  for(int i=0;i<ly;i++){

    for(int j=0;j<lx;j++){

    printf("%i ",matriz[i][j]);

    }
    printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Para un valor ingresado de 3, imprime:

```
3 4 5 6 
4 5 6 7 
5 6 7 8 
6 7 8 9
```

No se si era lo que deseabas, en todo caso necesitas agregar más detalles.